# How to use Haskell's `HashMap`?

Tags: haskell, hashmap

My expected result  as follows:

```
*Main> unify [Var "x",Var "x"] [Obj "a", Obj "a"] NoBindings

Bindings fromList [("x",a)]
```

However, this results in the following error:

```
Not in scope: data constructor H.HashMap
```

My code is as follows:

```
import qualified Data.List as L
import qualified Data.HashMap.Strict as H
import qualified Data.HashSet as S


data Pattern = Var String
         | GVar Int
         | Obj String
         | Funct String [Pattern]
         | Prim String
 deriving Eq

data Bindings = Fail
          | NoBindings
          | Bindings (H.HashMap String Pattern)
 deriving Show


unify :: [Pattern] -> [Pattern] ->Bindings -> Bindings
unify _ _ Fail              = Fail

unify [Var x,Var x1] [Obj a,Obj a1] NoBindings
        | x==x1     = Bindings (H.HashMap x a)
            | otherwise = error $show x1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Data.HashMap.Strict` module exposes the data type `HashMap`, but doesn't export its data constructors. It exports the `empty` and `singleton` functions instead:

```
empty :: HashMap k v
singleton :: (Hashable k) => k -> v -> HashMap k v
```

The latter can be used in your case:

```
unify [Var x,Var x1] [Obj a,Obj a1] NoBindings
        | x==x1     = Bindings (H.singleton x a)
        | otherwise = error $show x1
```